# Using one button at a time in arduino with multiple buttons

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

I made a code with which I can use multiple buttons at a time with my arduino. However, what I now want is to modify the code so that when one button is pressed no other buttons can work until the first button has been released.

Can anyone please help me with this? The code is as follows:

```c
#include <ezButton.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


ezButton button1 (22);
ezButton button2 (24);
ezButton button3 (26);
ezButton button4 (28);
ezButton button5 (30);


SoftwareSerial espSerial(18, 19);
String str;
int Myval = 255;


void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
espSerial.begin(9600);
button1.setDebounceTime(50);
button2.setDebounceTime(50);
button3.setDebounceTime(50);
button4.setDebounceTime(50);
button5.setDebounceTime(50);


} 

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
button1.loop();
button2.loop();
button3.loop();
button4.loop();
button5.loop();


int btn1S = button1.getState();
int btn2S = button2.getState();
int btn3S = button3.getState();
int btn4S = button4.getState();
int btn5S = button5.getState();

Serial.print("button 1 state: ");
Serial.println(btn1S);
Serial.print("button 2 state: ");
Serial.println(btn2S);
Serial.print("button 3 state: ");
Serial.println(btn3S);
Serial.print("button 4 state: ");
Serial.println(btn4S);
Serial.print("button 5 state: ");
Serial.println(btn5S);
  
if(button1.isPressed())
Serial.println("Fucntion for 22 is now on");

if(button1.isReleased())
Serial.println("Function for 22 is now off");

if(button2.isPressed())
Serial.println("Fucntion for 24 is now on");

if(button2.isReleased())
Serial.println("Function for 24 is now off");

if(button3.isPressed())
Serial.println("Fucntion for 26 is now on");

if(button3.isReleased())
Serial.println("Function for 26 is now off");

if(button4.isPressed())
Serial.println("Fucntion for 28 is now on");

if(button4.isReleased())
Serial.println("Function for 28 is now off");

if(button5.isPressed())
Serial.println("Fucntion for 30 is now on");

if(button5.isReleased())
Serial.println("Function for 30 is now off");

str = String("Coming from arduino: ")+String("Button 1 is now: ")+String(btn1S)+String("Button 2 is  
now: ")+String(btn2S)+String("Button 3 is now: ")+String(btn3S)+String("Button 4 is now: 
")+String(btn4S)+String("Button 5 is now: ")+String(btn5S);  
 espSerial.println(str);


 delay(1000);
}
```

The code is working but the only thing remaining is the condition that i want to put. Can anyone do the modification or tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it, is to define a global variable `int buttonDown = 0;` and then whenever a button is pressed, and no other button is pressed, assign the button number to `buttonDown`. When the button is released, reset `buttonDown` to `0`. Then you can easily check if `buttonDown` is `0` which means no other button is currently pressed.

Here is a minimal example:

```c
#include <ezButton.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

ezButton button1 (22);
ezButton button2 (24);

SoftwareSerial espSerial(18, 19);
String str;
int Myval = 255;
int buttonDown = 0; // Tracks the button state.

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    espSerial.begin(9600);
    button1.setDebounceTime(50);
    button2.setDebounceTime(50);
} 

void loop() {
    button1.loop();
    button2.loop();

    int btn1S = button1.getState();
    int btn2S = button2.getState();

    Serial.print("button 1 state: ");
    Serial.println(btn1S);
    Serial.print("button 2 state: ");
    Serial.println(btn2S);
  
    if(button1.isPressed() && buttonDown == 0){
        Serial.println("Function for 22 is now on");
        buttonDown = 1;
    }

    if(button1.isReleased() && buttonDown == 1){
        Serial.println("Function for 22 is now off");
        buttonDown = 0;
    }

    if(button2.isPressed() && buttonDown == 0){
        Serial.println("Function for 24 is now on");
        buttonDown = 2;
    }

    if(button2.isReleased() && buttonDown == 2)
        Serial.println("Function for 24 is now off");
    }

    delay(1000);
}
```

I think it should be pretty clear how to expand this further for your 5 buttons.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this and then i will definitely tell you how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using a boolean value set to false could work. Set the boolean value to true/1 when the button is released.